# Rate limiting signup API

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, rest, sails.js

We are are small start up and we are using SailsJS(which sits on top of NodeJS) on our backend. Ours is a API driven architecture. I want to implement rate limiting for most of the API's. I want to start with a small use case for Signup. Signup is a public API and currently anyone can access it to create accounts.

1. **My question is how can I prevent DoS attack by rate-limiting this public API?**
2. **Lets say I rate limit this API based on IP address. Then the problem would be if some users are in a same organization. They can have same IP address. So, how do we make sure they are rate limited properly?**

I really appreciate your suggestions and opinions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I have edited my question.

Comment: There's been a tremendous amount written about rate limiting all over the web.  There are multiple NPM modules for rate limiting and many articles and papers written on the topic.  It seems you should do your own research and then come back here with more specific questions after you've learned from what has already been written about and implemented.

Comment: Does signup need to be a programmatic API or can it be required to go through a web page?  If it can be required to go through a web page, you can use either a captcha or some other "prove you're a human" mechanism for the signup operation specifically.  Other API requests would need rate limiters though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.  I get your point now.  I think thats a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If signup does not have to be purely a programmatic API and can be required to go through a web page, then you can use either a captcha or some other "prove you're a human" mechanism for the signup operation specifically.  This will prevent programmatic DoS on the signup API since each request requires human intervention.

Other API requests would need rate limiters though to prevent abuse of an account that was already created.  Those subsequent API calls will presumably be referencing a specific account so you can handle the shared corporate IP address by rate limiting the account, not the IP address.

Comment: On the signup side, I have captcha on the frontend but I am also calling it programmatically in some other part of the code. 

So, having captcha for signup through UI and to programmatically access user creation sending some sort of token would be a good idea right?

Comment: @Ashish - If you're going to require captcha, then the only signup API you should present to the public is the one that goes through the captcha (essentially a form post that uses the captcha).  You can't also have another non-captcha public-facing signup API if you're gong to require use of the captcha.  You can have that internally, just not open to the public.

Comment: @Ashish - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn your some reputation points.